# Get a selected value from a select inside a paragraph

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a selection inside a paragraph and want to know what is the selected value, but I get null... Any help? Here is the code:

```
divWithInfo = document.createElement('div');
divWithInfo.class = 'divWithInfoControls';
divWithInfo.style.position = 'absolute';
divWithInfo.style.top = '10px';
divWithInfo.style.width = '100%';
divWithInfo.style.textAlign = 'center';
var groupToDisplay = '<p id="pSelectGroup" style="display: block;">Select the user group: ';
groupToDisplay += '<select id="selectGroup" onchange="applyGroupSelection()">';
groupToDisplay += '<option selected>Nothing selected</option>';
for ( var g in userGroups ) 
groupToDisplay += '<option>' + g + '</option>';
groupToDisplay += '</select></p>';
divWithInfo.innerHTML += groupToDisplay;
console.log ( document.getElementById( "selectGroup" ) );
```

when I apply the function onchange, the "document.getElementById" works fine, only in this case I got null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you've not appended your `divWithInfo` to the *#document* so `getElementById` can't find it in the *DOM tree*

Before you call `document.getElementById("selectGroup")`, remember to, e.g. `document.body.appendChild(divWithInfo)`.

If this is not an option, you may want to consider using `divWithInfo.querySelector`, i.e.

```
var foo = divWithInfo.querySelector("#selectGroup");
```

However, I'd try to avoid this and instead if a reference is required before appending, I would create entirely using *DOM* methods and **not using `.innerHTML`**